# Custom cursor distorts a little bit when rolling over movie clips

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a custom cursor in my flash project. That cursor consists of several parts (i.e. several movie clips inside of the cursor movie clip). And when the cursor rolls over different movie clips in my project, the parts of the cursor distort a little bit as though moving 1 pixel in relation to each other. And therefore the look of the whole cursor distorts a little. This happens every time the cursor crosses the boundary between the movie clips of the project (buttons, design pieces and so on). How can I make my cursor always retain one and the same look?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Code would help, namely the cursor attachment, movement, and any coded actions when rolling over the `MovieClips`. By the way, if your cursor isn't more than 32x32 pixels big, maybe you could try using `MouseCursorData`? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/MouseCursorData.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're doing something like this to position your custom cursor:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moved);

function moved(e:MouseEvent):void {
    customCursor.x = e.stageX;
    customCursor.y = e.stageY;
}
```

If so, when you move the mouse over a `MovieClip` or other element, your listener is receiving the event from that `DisplayObject` rather than the `Stage`. For some reason, `DisplayObject`s positioned at sub pixel values produce `e.stageX` and `e.stageY` values which aren't exactly the same as `stage.mouseX` and `stage.mouseY`, so your custom cursor elements are jumping slightly as the pixel values round differently.

Try using the `Stage` mouse position directly instead:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moved);

function moved(e:MouseEvent):void {
    customCursor.x = stage.mouseX;
    customCursor.y = stage.mouseY;
}
```